# Texmaker on Mac doesn't like my \section{}s

Tags: errors

I have just made a clean install on a Mac I'm using at the moment. Everything seems good except when I compile, I have the error

> Missing number, treated as zero. s

The error tells me that this occurs on line `xxx`, where `xxx` is everywhere I have `\section{}`

Comment: That means that there is a mistake in some code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in the \section{} lines? Or elsewhere? I am trying to compile a (40 page) document that I made in Texmaker on a Windows machine, and there were no errors last time... :s

Comment: @User17670 David is referring to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I guess that the problem is related to the encoding. She/He did the file on Windows.

Comment: @hpesoj626 There are no 'errors' in my code. It's a cross-platform problem/ machine issue. Given this, a MWE is not appropriate IMO. I have answered my question below for those who may have the same problem in future.

Comment: @User17670 If it's really true that you found a document that compiles in one distribution (that's more relevant than the editor) on one machine and not in another distribution on another machine, that that is extremely interesting and it would be a worthwhile bug to fix.  I would encourage you to trim down the 40-page document to one page and see if it still has this issue.  Then we can reopen the question.  On the other hand, you might also find a different source for the error message.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang What do mean by 'trim down'? To find the error-causing lines (see answer) I kept commenting-out more and more non-vital parts to my preamble until it loaded, then I added back as much I as could until I found the precise lines that caused the fatal errors. As a side-note, I don't understand why my problem is 'too localized' - many people will swap between different distributions - especially if multiple people are working on the same document.

Comment: @User17670 Trimming down means removing most parts of your code, retaining the parts that exhibit the problem. Oftentimes, doing this isolates the problem. (Sometimes, this enables you to solve your own problem.) Whatever is left is called a minimal working/non-working example (MWE)

Comment: @hpesoj626 which is pretty much what I did... But whatever - it's solved now, at least to the extent that I can edit and compile, can't wait to get back to my previous set-up (PC, distribution, shortcuts etc.)

Comment: The link hpesoj626 gave you goes to a page about minimizing examples.  With a copy of your error-causing file, try *removing* the parts that do not effect the error until only the parts that do remain.  Then you could post a half-screenful of code and we could easily test it to find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to 'comment out' the following lines:

`\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}`

`\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

This seems to be a cross-platform issue/ machine issue, since there was absolutely no problem in Texmaker on my Windows PC.